# iOS - Moving from iCal Event into Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, icalendar

I'm in the middle of planning a project that would utilise the ability to create custom events from within an iOS application.

At the moment i've found plenty of code that allows you to do this but ideally I would like the user to be able to then navigate back into the application once the iCal reminder has fired, in a similar way a push notification does once the user hits the view button.

I've had a detailed look around but cannot find anything, does anyone know if this possible?

If it's not possible, does anyone know of a way to create dynamic push notifications from within the app?

Thanks in advance.